# creating pojo of mule-config.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, mule

I have mule-config.xml file of which I want to generated pojo objects, using which I could dynamically generate the mule-config.xml file. I would provide a mule-config-default.xml file and I would load this as reference file and let the program to create further spring-beans or any other configuration and finally save this file as mule-config.xml file.

So I have tried the following.

> Using jaxb/xjc tool to generate the pojo's and using this pojos I would create xml. But I have been failing doing so, as I have quite a lot of namespace references.

Any other idea I could use.

Comment: Did you mavenize you project and let maven execute xjc to generate pojo? I tried that but you need to create your own jaxbbinding.xml

Comment: No, I was doing it manually, And yes perhpas I would need to do the jaxbbinding thingy